# Download the main page from angular

Tags: angular

I have a chat where I receive the message from the server.
I have a button and I need to make it let me download the chat in html format (so I have to download the entire componenet of the chat) how can I do this?

Comment: Please provide a [minimal reproducable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). This question is too generic.